# Set application/json as header in Volley Stringrequest for POST method

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I want to set application/json as the Content type but even after overriding getBodyContentType() to application/json getting Volley server error.

```
  StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        listener.onResponse(response);
                        Log.d("Response",response.toString());

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        if (response.length() == 0) {
                            Log.d("ERROR : ", "NO RESPONSE");
                        } else {
                            Log.d("ERROR : ", "EXCEPTION");
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                    listener.onError(error.toString());
                    Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("macId", macValue);
            return params;
        }
      @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json";
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(postRequest);
}
```

Note : please provide the answers in code snippet

Comment: You can set the headers in the `getParamas()` method.

Comment: you could content-type with application/json by overide getHeaders http://stackoverflow.com/a/17445275/1842454

Answer (score 0):

override following method:

```
  public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    }
```

and override getHeaders as well and pass nothing:

```
   @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        return headers;
    }
```

it will work.

Comment: got this error " Error.Response: com.android.volley.ServerError "

Comment: post your complete error. VolleyError contains   .getMessage().

Comment: E/Volley: [11979] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http://10.23.64.77:8080/Apparel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136191/unexpected-response-code-500-url-api-android-app

Answer (score 0):

First check your webservice in postman...